# Query on DataTable object error is The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have facing some error while select query in Linq.

Error is,

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Code is below,

```
dt_TDATA = new DataTable();
dt_TDATA.Columns.Add("MATNR", typeof(string));
dt_TDATA.Columns.Add("MAKTX", typeof(string));
dt_TDATA.Columns.Add("PHY_STK", typeof(Int32));
dt_TDATA.Columns.Add("LABST", typeof(Int32));    

DataTable dtDealMat = GetDealMat(); //Get from Store procedure

var MatData = from Data in dt_TDATA.AsEnumerable()
              join mat in dtDealMat on Data.Field<string>("MATNR") equals mat.Field<string>("vMATNR")
              select new {
                    MATNR = Data.Field<string>("MATNR"),
                    MAKTX = Data.Field<string>("MAKTX"),
                    PHY_STK = Data.Field<string>("PHY_STK"),
                    LABST = Data.Field<string>("LABST")
              };

//GetDealMat() function
private DataTable GetDealMat()
{
    clsMOU objMast = new clsMOU();
    objMast.vUserID = clsAppSession.SessionUserID;
    DataTable dtDealMat = new DataTable();
    dtDealMat.Columns.Add("vMATNR", typeof(string));

    dtDealMat = objMast.GET_DelMatMapping();
    return dtDealMat;
}
```

Please help in above query..

Comment: MATNR both are string vMATNR is from Store procedure

Comment: What database platform are you using? Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` for all relevant tables.

Comment: using sql server and c#

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` for all relevant tables.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are not reading second datatable  (dtDealMat.AsEnumerable())

```
       var MatData = from Data in dt_TDATA.AsEnumerable()
          join mat in dtDealMat.AsEnumerable() on Data.Field<string>("MATNR") equals mat.Field<string>("vMATNR")
          select new {
                MATNR = Data.Field<string>("MATNR"),
                MAKTX = Data.Field<string>("MAKTX"),
                PHY_STK = Data.Field<string>("PHY_STK"),
                LABST = Data.Field<string>("LABST")
          };
```